# Quarter wise growth calculation in r

Tags: r, loops

I have quarter wise plan revenue value of different business segment. I have the following data set:

```
segment  Q1_Revenue  Q2_Revenue  Q3_Revenue  Q4_Revenue

 A             1002         100         279         787          

 B              985         300         658         456

 C              478         745         5478        100
```

or:

```
revenues <- data.frame(segment = c('A','B','C'),
           Q1_Revenue = c(1002,985,478),
           Q2_Revenue = c(100,300,745),
           Q3_Revenue = c(279,658,5478),
           Q4_Revenue = c(787, 456, 100),
           stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to calculate quarter to quarter growth using loop so that it would be dynamic. I am able to do this by using SQL. But I want to use loop over column so that I can get all quarter wise growth .e.g:

- Q4 to Q1 growth, Q4 to Q2 growth, Q4 to Q3 growth;
- Q3 to Q2 growth,Q3 to Q1 growth,Q2 to Q1 growth.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you absolutely need loops? The _dplyr_ or _DT_ (data table) packages would allow you to do these operations in a dynamic, adaptable way, but do not involve writing loop statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. It assumes the columns are ordered correctly to start.

```
growth = list()
for (base_q in 2:ncol(revenues)) {
    for (growth_q in 2:base_q) {
        if (base_q == growth_q) next
        name = paste(names(revenues)[base_q], "to", names(revenues)[growth_q], sep = "_")
        growth[[name]] = revenues[[base_q]] / revenues[[growth_q]]
    }   
}
data.frame(segment = revenues[[1]], growth)
#   segment Q2_Revenue_to_Q1_Revenue Q3_Revenue_to_Q1_Revenue Q3_Revenue_to_Q2_Revenue Q4_Revenue_to_Q1_Revenue Q4_Revenue_to_Q2_Revenue
# 1       A                0.0998004                0.2784431                 2.790000                0.7854291                7.8700000
# 2       B                0.3045685                0.6680203                 2.193333                0.4629442                1.5200000
# 3       C                1.5585774               11.4602510                 7.353020                0.2092050                0.1342282
#   Q4_Revenue_to_Q3_Revenue
# 1               2.82078853
# 2               0.69300912
# 3               0.01825484
```

Answer (score 1):

The question did not specify what the output should look like but here are a some alternatives and approaches.  No packages are used.

The 3d array in (1) is particularly convenient if we wanted to take slices such as just looking at one segment or one quarter and can also easily be reformed into a 2d ftable in multiple ways, as shown.

The output matrix in (2) is more compact and can be displayed in original or transposed format.

**1) outer** Try applying `outer` to each row.  We produce a list (one element for each of A, B and C) and simplify it to a 3d array we which display along with some alternative `ftable` displays.

For example, for A we have Q4/Q1 = 787/1002 - 1 =  -0.2145709 which is the number found in A at the numerator Q4 and denominator Q1.

```
growthMat <- function(x) {
   mat <- matrix(outer(tail(x, -1), head(x, -1), "/") - 1, length(x)-1)
   mat[row(mat) < col(mat)] <- NA
   dimnames(mat) <- list(Num = tail(names(x), -1), Den = head(names(x), -1))
   list(mat)
}

L <- setNames(apply(revenues[-1], 1, growthMat), revenues[[1]])
arr <- simplify2array(lapply(L, "[[", 1))
```

giving this 3d array:

```
> arr
, ,  = A

                Den
    Num          Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue
      Q2_Revenue -0.9001996         NA         NA
      Q3_Revenue -0.7215569       1.79         NA
      Q4_Revenue -0.2145709       6.87   1.820789

    , ,  = B

                Den
    Num          Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue
      Q2_Revenue -0.6954315         NA         NA
      Q3_Revenue -0.3319797   1.193333         NA
      Q4_Revenue -0.5370558   0.520000 -0.3069909

    , ,  = C

                Den
    Num          Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue
      Q2_Revenue  0.5585774         NA         NA
      Q3_Revenue 10.4602510  6.3530201         NA
      Q4_Revenue -0.7907950 -0.8657718 -0.9817452
```

or as a 2d `"ftable"` object:

```
> ftable(arr)
                                A          B          C
Num        Den                                         
Q2_Revenue Q1_Revenue  -0.9001996 -0.6954315  0.5585774
           Q2_Revenue          NA         NA         NA
           Q3_Revenue          NA         NA         NA
Q3_Revenue Q1_Revenue  -0.7215569 -0.3319797 10.4602510
           Q2_Revenue   1.7900000  1.1933333  6.3530201
           Q3_Revenue          NA         NA         NA
Q4_Revenue Q1_Revenue  -0.2145709 -0.5370558 -0.7907950
           Q2_Revenue   6.8700000  0.5200000 -0.8657718
           Q3_Revenue   1.8207885 -0.3069909 -0.9817452
```

or this one:

```
> ftable(arr, row.vars = 3)
  Num Q2_Revenue                       Q3_Revenue                       Q4_Revenue                      
  Den Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue Q1_Revenue Q2_Revenue Q3_Revenue

A     -0.9001996         NA         NA -0.7215569  1.7900000         NA -0.2145709  6.8700000  1.8207885
B     -0.6954315         NA         NA -0.3319797  1.1933333         NA -0.5370558  0.5200000 -0.3069909
C      0.5585774         NA         NA 10.4602510  6.3530201         NA -0.7907950 -0.8657718 -0.9817452
```

**2) combn**  The first two lines compute the growth rates giving `mat` and then the last two lines add row and column names

```
growth <- function(nms) revenues[[nms[2]]]/revenues[[nms[1]]] - 1
mat <- combn(names(revenues[-1]), 2, growth)
pasteNames <- function(nms) paste(rev(nms), collapse = ":")
dimnames(mat) <- list(revenues[[1]], combn(names(revenues[-1]), 2, pasteNames))
```

giving this 3x6 matrix:

```
> mat
  Q2_Revenue:Q1_Revenue Q3_Revenue:Q1_Revenue Q4_Revenue:Q1_Revenue
A            -0.9001996            -0.7215569            -0.2145709
B            -0.6954315            -0.3319797            -0.5370558
C             0.5585774            10.4602510            -0.7907950
  Q3_Revenue:Q2_Revenue Q4_Revenue:Q2_Revenue Q4_Revenue:Q3_Revenue
A              1.790000             6.8700000             1.8207885
B              1.193333             0.5200000            -0.3069909
C              6.353020            -0.8657718            -0.9817452
```

or transposed:

```
> t(mat)
                               A          B          C
Q2_Revenue:Q1_Revenue -0.9001996 -0.6954315  0.5585774
Q3_Revenue:Q1_Revenue -0.7215569 -0.3319797 10.4602510
Q4_Revenue:Q1_Revenue -0.2145709 -0.5370558 -0.7907950
Q3_Revenue:Q2_Revenue  1.7900000  1.1933333  6.3530201
Q4_Revenue:Q2_Revenue  6.8700000  0.5200000 -0.8657718
Q4_Revenue:Q3_Revenue  1.8207885 -0.3069909 -0.9817452
```

**Update:** Several improvements and alternative outputs within (1).  Also added (2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this- (modified)

```
growth <- sapply(seq(1:3), function(x) 
           {
            data.frame((revenues[,paste0("Q",seq(4, x + 1, -1),"_Revenue")] -
                        revenues[,paste0("Q",x,"_Revenue")]) / 
                        revenues[,paste0("Q",seq(4, x + 1, -1),"_Revenue")])
           })
growth <- cbind(growth[[1]], growth[[2]], growth[[3]])
names(growth) <- sapply(seq(1:3), function(x) paste0("Q",seq(4,x+1,-1)," over Q",x))
rownames(growth) <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

Comment: I did not see that you wanted to calculate the growth for all quarters and not just with respect to Q4. I have edited the script to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`combn` can be really helpful here.  First we use it with the `FUN` argument to get our ratios:

```
ratios <- combn(names(revenues)[-1], 2, function(x) revenues[[x[2]]]/revenues[[x[1]]])
```

Since the columns are in order we know that the second input in `combn` will always be the more recent quarter.  If that wasn't the case, we might have to call `sort` on the column names or something like that to get the order consistent.

Next we use `combn` again to make our column names:

```
colindex <- combn(names(revenues)[-1], 2, simplify = FALSE)
colnamevals <- vapply(colindex, paste, character(1), collapse = " to ")
```

Finally we can set the names on our matrix:

```
colnames(ratios) <- colnamevals
rownames(ratios) <- revenues[["segment"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are approaches using `do` from the `dplyr` package and `map` from the `purrr` package. This ended up being more complicated than I initially expected. Or, more likely, I made it more complicated than it needed to be. I'd be interested in ways to simplify either approach.

#### Using `do` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

revenues %>% melt(id.var="segment") %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(outer(.$value, .$value, `/`) - 1)) %>%
  set_names(., c("Segment", paste0("Q",1:4))) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter=names(.)[-1]) %>%
  melt(id.var=c("Segment","Quarter")) %>%
  filter(substr(Quarter, 2,2) > substr(variable,2,2)) %>%
  dcast(Segment + Quarter ~ variable)
```

> ```
>   Segment Quarter         Q1         Q2         Q3
> 1       A      Q2 -0.9001996         NA         NA
> 2       A      Q3 -0.7215569  1.7900000         NA
> 3       A      Q4 -0.2145709  6.8700000  1.8207885
> 4       B      Q2 -0.6954315         NA         NA
> 5       B      Q3 -0.3319797  1.1933333         NA
> 6       B      Q4 -0.5370558  0.5200000 -0.3069909
> 7       C      Q2  0.5585774         NA         NA
> 8       C      Q3 10.4602510  6.3530201         NA
> 9       C      Q4 -0.7907950 -0.8657718 -0.9817452
> ```

Or in long format (I've shown output only for `segment` A for brevity):

```
revenues %>% melt(id.var="segment") %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(outer(.$value, .$value, `/`) - 1)) %>%
  set_names(., c("Segment", paste0("Q",1:4))) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter=names(.)[-1]) %>%
  melt(id.var=c("Segment","Quarter")) %>%
  filter(substr(Quarter, 2,2) > substr(variable,2,2)) %>%
  mutate(Quarters=paste0(Quarter,"/",variable)) %>%
  select(Segment, Quarters, Growth_Ratio=value) %>%
  arrange(Segment, Quarters)
```

> ```
>    Segment Quarters Growth_Ratio
> 1        A    Q2/Q1   -0.9001996
> 2        A    Q3/Q1   -0.7215569
> 3        A    Q3/Q2    1.7900000
> 4        A    Q4/Q1   -0.2145709
> 5        A    Q4/Q2    6.8700000
> 6        A    Q4/Q3    1.8207885
> ```

#### Using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)

revenues %>% 
  split(.$segment) %>%
  map(.f= ~ data.frame(Quarter=.x[1], outer(as.numeric(.x[-1]), as.numeric(.x[-1]), `/`) - 1)) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  set_names(., c("Segment", paste0("Q",1:4))) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter=rep(names(.)[-1], length(unique(Segment)))) %>%
  melt(id.var=c("Segment","Quarter")) %>%
  filter(substr(Quarter, 2,2) > substr(variable,2,2)) %>%
  dcast(Segment + Quarter ~ variable)
```

Comment: I don't know who is doing all these downvotings of correct answers but I have upvoted you to counter that.